# The request for <procedure> failed because <procedure> is a procedure object. SQL error 37000

Tags: php, sql, sql-server, odbc, procedure

I'm trying to use the SDK for the 123insight MRP system. In the SDK, there is one particular routine called `SDK.BOMInsertSDK`. Whenever I attempt to execute a SQL query from PHP through the ODBC driver, this fails with the error.

```
Warning: odbc_exec(): SQL error: [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][SQL Server]
The request for procedure 'BOMInsertSDK' failed because 'BOMInsertSDK' is a 
procedure object., SQL state 37000
```

What confuses me about this error: I can type the query in to Microsoft SQL Server Management Express and the query will execute successfully. Also, some other routines like `ProductionSDK. SubOperationTestResultBooking` work, but *others* like `SDK.PartInsertSDK` do *not* work.  It seems almost random as to what I can execute and what I cannot. What could cause this?

Here's a screenshot of the relevant SDK documentation:

[image]

Here is my query, in case it matters:

```
EXECUTE [SDK].[BOMInsertSDK]    @strParentPartNumber = "20-01-702", 
                                @nSequenceNumber = 1234, 
                                @strChildPartNumber = "01-07-001-R", 
                                @decScrapPercentage = 0, 
                                @decQuantity = 1, @blnIsPrime = 1,
                                @strMethodType = "Manufactured", 
                                @strVersionNumber = "0001", 
                                @blnInheritSerial = 0, 
                                @strComments = "no comment"
```

Any advice appreciated.

Comment: Unfortunately you didn't show the PHP code that executes the procedure, but have you used SQL Profiler to view the actual SQL being executed on the server? It's possible that PHP and/or ODBC are changing the query text in some way before executing it. And the correct delimiter for strings in TSQL is a single quote, not a double quote; you might want to change that and see if it makes any difference.

Comment: The data you are sending to database does not match the table exactly.